# Android Theme Panel whole width

Tags: android, xml, width, panel

I want an activity to take the whole screen's width but not the screen's height.
and, I want to see the activity that is below.

I use this in the manifest :

```
<activity
        android:name="activities.Dialoger"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Panel"/>
```

But, the "dialoger" doesn't use the whole width even if I wrote this in the XML file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

So, how the activity can take the whole width?

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/semi_transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 : 
No, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: ok <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/semi_transparent" android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical">. Ok try this.

Comment: No...
With the Theme "@android:style/Theme.Panel", the width behaves like a "wrap_content". And, me, I want it behaves like a "match_parent".

The height doesn't matter to me.

But, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's ok.

I found the solution.
In the Manifest :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Panel"
```

And in the XML :

```
android:minWidth="400dp"
```

Comment: 400dp seems awfully arbitrary...?